# How to declare an array of items in tcsh that separates on multilines?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I'm trying to declare an array of items in `tcsh` that separates on multilines. I tried:

```
set ignore_array = (
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
)
```

Also tried:

```
set ignore_array = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
}
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using line continuations (escaping each newline):

```
set ignore_array = ( \
    'a' \
    'b' \
    'c' \
)
```

The form with `{ ... }` is invalid, as far as I know.

Comment: It's really looks ugly. Is it the only way?

Comment: @vesii The grammar requires the assignment to be on a single line. You present a single line to the shell by escaping the newlines.

Comment: I see thank you. What would be the easiest way to check if element in that array without additional `for` loop?

Comment: @vesii That sounds like a separate question.